# Compare date values in Wordpress Wp_Query

Tags: wordpress, compare

I’m running a WordPress website with around 35 000 customs posts.
Each post has a birthday value date (format DD/MM/YYYY)  stored in a ACF field named birthday

Example :

```
$birtday_date = get_field("birthday"); //example 02/07/1955
```

I would like to run 2 queries in order to compare each post birthday value with the 34999 other birthday dates values in my wordpress, count and display the number of people older and younger.
Here is my code but it doesn’t work as I don’t really understand how to compare a value

Can you help me with that ?

```
<?php
$args = array(  // args and query to look for older people that $birthday_date
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'post_type' => 'people',
'meta_key' => 'birthday',
'meta_value' => $birthday_date,
'compare' => '>',
'type' => 'DATE'

);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
$superior = $query->found_posts;
wp_reset_query();



$args2 = array(  // args and query to look for younger people that $birthday_date
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'post_type' => 'people',
'meta_key' => 'birthday',
'meta_value' => $birthday_date,
'compare' => '<',
'type' => 'DATE'

);
$query2 = new WP_Query($args2);
$inferior = $query2->found_posts;
wp_reset_query();

echo $superior; // should display the number of older people but display number of people born the same day than $birthday_date
echo $inferior; // should display the number of younger people but display number of people born the same day than $birthday_date
```

Thanks for your help.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You probably only need one actual query here, I'd suggest using just get_posts instead since you're not looping anything.  And you can just count the difference from the total number of posts in the post type.

```
<?php

$birthday_date = get_field("birthday");

// Count the total number of posts in the post type and get the ones that are published.  Note this shorthand only works in PHP5

$total_posts = wp_count_posts('people')->publish;

// Use this for PHP4
// $count_posts = wp_count_posts('people');
// $total_posts = $count_posts->publish;

$args = array(  // args and query to look for older people that $birthday_date
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'post_type' => 'people',
'meta_query' => array(
   'key' => 'birthday',
   'value' => $birthday_date,
   'compare' => '>',
   'type' => 'DATE'
)
);

// Get the posts with the older birthdays
$older_birthdays = get_posts($args);

// Count the number of posts in the older birthdays 
$num_of_older_bdays = count($older_birthdays);

// Calculate the other birthdays remaining
$num_of_younger_bdays = $total_posts - $older_birthdays;

// Display your birthday counts
echo $num_of_older_bdays;
echo $num_of_younger_bdays;
```